# Vim - how to run current python3 file in the python shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim

I have a file called myFile.py on my desktop. This is the file:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        self = node
        while node.next:
            print(node.data)
            node = node.next
        return node.data
```

I normally edit the file in IDLE. In IDLE I can click Run->Run Module (F5) to run the file. After clicking "Run Module" in IDLE, it opens up the python shell and I can create a Node and work with the current file.

I don't use IDLE any more (I use GVim to type / edit code). Is it possible with GVim to run the current open file in the python shell?

I tried doing

```
:!python3 %
```

but when I do this, GVim just says:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and when I press enter, nothing happens.

Note: I am using Python3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `:!python3 &` you are actually running a shell that executes the command `python3 myFile.py`. That will run your program non-interactively and, as is, your program does nothing, it just defines a class and ends.

You can force the interactive mode with `:!python3 -i %`.

Alternatively you can do `:!python3` without arguments: it will launch an interactive python shell. There you can write `import myFile` or `from myFile import *` and then create your `Node` objects.

Comment: hm, interesting. My file is called "LinkedList.py". When I do :!python3 without arguments, and then "import LinkedList" it says "ImportError: No module named 'LinkedList'". Same with if I do "import LinkedList.py".  Any idea why? ":!python3 -i %" works though, so thanks for that.

Comment: @user2719875: That's probably because the current directory where GVim is running is not the directory where the file is. You'd need to move there (`cd`) or import the full path of the module. The `%` already includes the full path of the file, so it just works.